# What's the need for the protocol T.120

Tags: rtp

I recently heard about the protocol T.120 for transmission of streaming text in RTP.
I was wondering why is such a protocol needed for text, since text is not like audio or video such that loss of a few packet is tolerable.
and that too the text is sent over UDP.

Why not send the streaming text over TCP connection??

Regards,
Vineet

Answer (score 0):

T.120 isn't just used to stream text. Is is a protocol for for screen and application sharing.

When used with H.323, T.120 uses a separate H.245 connection, which is nothing else than a separate TCP connection (unless H.245 is tunneld, then it shares the signalling connection).

Comment: so does it mean that when used for text, no encoding is used and text is transmitted in ASCII(for instance) as in case of a TCP connection?